# What does a Copper Dragon's Slow Gas do?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

The Copper Dragon in the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm#copperDragon) has two breath weapons, one of which is a cone of slow gas. The description says:

> A copper dragon has two types of breath weapon, a line of acid and a cone of slow gas. Creatures within the cone must succeed on a Fortitude save or be slowed for 1d6 rounds plus 1 round per age category of the dragon.

However, the [Conditions summary](http://www.d20srd.org/indexes/conditions.htm) does not show **slowed** as a condition.

There is, however, a [spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/slow.htm) by the name of Slow. Is anyone hit by the cone supposed to be put under the effects of that spell, or is there an actual Slowed condition floating around somewhere that I cannot find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes exactly, slowed as the spell. There is no other slow to be found.

Comment: Do you have anything to back it up? Just to be extra certain.

Comment: Only the inexorable march of logic.  You can't prove a negative, but there's no other slow.  You're way overthinking this.

Comment: @Erik: 3.x rules are nowhere near systematized enough to nitpick this particular question. If the first choice doesn't exist, shrug and move on to fallbacks.

Comment: Alright, fair enough :)